# Unable to use a async method on button action in js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react development
I have a js file in a react app, which has a button

```
<CardFooter className="text-center">
                    block
                    className="btn-round"
                    color="info"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick= "handleVerify()"
                    size="lg"
```

I am getting warning as `handleverify` is defined but never used

```
async function handleVerify(){
 // e.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch('/api/emailVerifier', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),

  });
  const body = await response.text();
  
  this.setState({ responseToPost: body });

};
```

Comment: try this - onClick={handleVerify}

Comment: tried it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick should looks like this:

```
onClick={() => handleVerify()}
```

Comment: sinc my repo is less than 15 my upvote to ur answer is n t visible

Comment: m using componentDidMount, getting same warning for this also

Answer (score 0):

In componentDidMount you can make something like this

```
     async function handleVerify(){
         // e.preventDefault();
          const response = await fetch('/api/emailVerifier', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        
            body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
        
          });
          return await response.text();
        }
    componentDidMount() {
       handleVerify().then(body=> {
  this.setState({ responseToPost:  });

})
    
    }
```